# How Do I get my Discord Bot to Send a private message to another user using their user ID,I tried the following but it did not work

Tags: python, discord

```
 import discord 
 import os
 import pytz
 import datetime
 import asyncio 
 class MyClient(discord.Client):
  
  async def on_ready(self):
    print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))
  
  async def dm(ctx):
    print('Message from {0.author}: {0.content}'.format(message))
    if message.author.bot:
     return
     user = await client.get_user(UserID)
     await client.send(user,'Hello')
   client = MyClient()
   client.run('BOTID')
```

I Ran my bot using this and when I tested it by messaging the bot, it did not reply. Must the user that I am sending to be in the same server, can I send it to a user that is not in the same server?

Answer (score 0):

i dont think "dm" function is available in discord.py, use this instead:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()
token = "token goes here"

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged as {client.user}")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # add this or ur bot will a spam bot (will result in spamming message after u send only one message)
    if message.author.bot: return
    if message.channel.type is discord.ChannelType.private: #private channel = dm
        await message.channel.send("dm")
    else:
        await message.channel.send("not dm")

client.run(token)
```

and if u want it as object:

```
import discord

token = "token goes here"

class Bot(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f"Logged as {self.user}")
    
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author.bot: return
        if message.channel.type is discord.ChannelType.private:
            print(f"Got a message from {message.author} in private: {message.content}")
            await message.channel.send("dm")
            return
        else:
            print(f"Got a message from {message.author} in public: {message.content}")
            await message.channel.send("not dm")
            return

bot = Bot()
bot.run(token)
```

btw object based version has a message logger (Got a message from someone in public/private: msg) but i wont add it in functional version (due to TabError).